# Why doesn’t “sudo -n true” work inside brackets in loop/conditional?

Tags: macos, bash, sudo

I have a loop that will prompt for the `sudo` password until it gets it correct. The why isn’t relevant, lets just say it’s part of a bigger script and other solutions aren’t appropriate.

```
until sudo -n true 2> /dev/null; do
  read -s -p "Password:" sudo_password
  sudo -S -v <<< "${sudo_password}" 2> /dev/null
done
```

This works very well. However, it does not work when inside brackets

```
until [[ $(sudo -n true 2> /dev/null) ]]; do
  read -s -p "Password:" sudo_password
  sudo -S -v <<< "${sudo_password}" 2> /dev/null
done
```

I’ve tried this in a myriad of ways, with both loops and conditionals. I even went so far as doing

```
until [[ $(sudo -n true 2> /dev/null; echo "$?") -ne 0 ]]; do
  read -s -p "Password:" sudo_password
  sudo -S -v <<< "${sudo_password}" 2> /dev/null

  # check exit status is indeed 0
  sudo -n true 2> /dev/null
  echo "$?"
done
```

This also does not work, and I do not understand why. Actually, this case always returns `0` (according to the last `echo "$?"`) even if the password is wrong, but it never jumps out of the loop, even if the password is correct, which is even weirder.

---

**Edit:** Just realised why the last one didn’t work, while it seemed to in other cases. With that particular comparison, it should’ve been `while`, not `until`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step by step.

1. `until sudo -n true 2> /dev/null; do` this evaluate `sudo -n true`, discard standard error, and provide return code to `until`.
2. `$(sudo -n true 2> /dev/null)` this

   2.1 evaluate `sudo -n true`,

   2.2 discard standard error 2> /dev/null

   2.3 take standard output *empty*
3. `until [[ $(sudo -n true 2> /dev/null) ]]; do` this

   3.1-3.3 same as above

   3.4 use [[ *empty* ]] this is most likely an error
4. `until [[ $(sudo -n true 2> /dev/null; echo "$?") -ne 0 ]]; do` this

   4.1 to 4.4 same as above

   4.5 compare *empty* to 0

The first line is the corret one, `sudo` provide a return code, simply use it.

A common error is to mistake the return code: an integer (usualy 0 or 1 or 2 (No such file or directory)), with ouput (can be anything, text or binary).

Shells (bash/dash/whateversh) can be told to watch return code (`set -e`), or in `test`.

Comment: “A common error is to mistake return code an integer (usualy 0 or 1 or 2 (No such file or directory), with ouput (can be anything, text or binary)” That is a good insight, and explains the issue well, thank you.